# How to programmatically detect when the device wakes up or is unlocked after Oreo update?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo, android-broadcastreceiver

My application was showing screen on when device unlocked . For that i was using broadcast receiver "action_user_present" but  now after Oreo OS arrived my application is not showing any screen and i could not fetching "action_user_present" broadcast .

This is my patent application and i need to get event when phone would unlocked So please help  me for that

Comment: may be this link will help https://medium.com/exploring-android/exploring-background-execution-limits-on-android-oreo-ab384762a66c